# perl: cannot connect to mongodb server

Tags: mongodb, perl

I am having a problem connecting to the mongodb server from my Perl script.

- the mongodb server is running ok on localhost port 27017
- I can access the mongodb server via the mongod shell and via mongo Compass (Community Edition)

But on trying to connect via Perl, I am getting the error:

```
"MongoDB::SelectionError: No readable server available for matching read preference primary. MongoDB server status:
Topology type: Single; Member status:
localhost:27017 (type: Unknown, error: MongoDB::NetworkError: Could not 
connect to 'localhost:27017': Bad address )"
```

The simple perlscript is:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use open qw/:std :utf8/;
use IO::Handle;
use MongoDB;

#my $client = MongoDB->connect('mongodb://localhost');   
# connect to localhost:27017
my $client = MongoDB::MongoClient->new(host => 'localhost', port => 27017);
my $db   = $client->get_database( 'example');
my $people_coll = $db->get_collection('people');
$db->drop;
```

The line:

```
my $client = MongoDB::MongoClient->new(host => 'localhost', port => 27017);
```

does not appear to throw the error, but trying to create or amend a dbase does. I have reviewed similar questions on mongodb connection issues and have tried turning off firewall, remove `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` (although I couldn't locate this file anywhere).

Any help is most welcome!

Comment: "Bad address" is an interesting error there. That's `EFAULT`.

Comment: @melpomene I think it's actually `"Bad address "` with a space at the end.

Comment: Perhaps for some reason localhost cannot be resolved. Can you ping localhost? Can you try 127.0.0.1 in place of localhost? Can you show an example of a successful connection via the mongo shell?

Comment: IPv4 or IPv6 do you use? "For IPv6 support, you must have a recent version of IO::Socket::IP installed. " - [metacpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/MongoDB::MongoClient)

Comment: @helmy Problem solved by explicitly stating 127.0.0.1 in place of localhost, as per your suggestion. (Pinging 127.0.0.1 was ok). I'm not sure why localhost not recognised from within my Perl script
Many thanks for all help - I can now push ahead with some prototype development.

Answer (score 2):

By default MongoDB Server is available to 127.0.0.1
So change localhost by 127.0.0.1

Then if you want to customize this, so you can access this MongoDB Server from other computer client check out this post: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/mongodb-server-service-windows-10-daniel-pe%C3%B1a/